# Why Can't I Use Format Selected in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use format selected to convert a file to a link - I know it is a lot easier to just type `<a href="..." ...>...</a>` but alas I'm following a book and trying to do everything exactly as they say and I'm having issues with even using the format selected options.

Nothing comes up when I click it in Edit menu, nothing happens when I right click the selection and choose format selection, nothing happens when I try to use the toolbar I added to get it to work (everything is grayed out).

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

The selection is on `default.aspx`

Format selected = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? @RandyE

Comment: wow sorry..I put in a href (only with the <)for a hyperlink but Stackoverflow didn't interpret it correctly

Comment: finally getting to understand your question. However, I won't be able to help since I "almost never" use the designer tools for code editing...I only use randomly if I need to preview/visualize a UI before debugging. IMHO, they seem to be very misleading and I get the feeling that it adds too much separation from the actual programming tasks...and I think that's the "general opinion" of many programming enthusiasts out there. Good luck anyway!

Comment: Thanks @Leo I figured it out though. This is why I don't like using these types of tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It is because the format only works in Design view. I honestly never realized that because I don't use these silly things as its faster to just type out the markup.

So - Format Selected will only work in design view. If you're in source view it does not work.

Comment: +1 not that I'm a fan of the designer tools (as said above) but this could help "web designers" with limited programming skills

Comment: You're absolutely right. This book is one of those that actually tries to show you around the IDE a little more than just telling you one way of doing something, they always offer the shortcut, keyboard shortcut, and roundabout way of doing things. For reference it is Beginning ASP.NET 4.5.1 in C# and VB if anyone comes along later.

Comment: Please consider marking your answer as accepted after the time limit so other people can find it.